# Display miniatures with ProFTPd

Tags: image, browser, ftp, proftpd

I am currently using ProFTPd on my server to offer a lot of storage solutions for my family, friends, ...

Currently, we decided to put our pictures in common without giving Google access to it *via* Picasa.

So i created an user `ftpuser` on my server, forbid him ssh and jailed him to his home before giving access to my friends.

Here is my problem : many of them want to select some particular pictures when downloading, and then I would like to allow than, when connecting *via* a web browser (with the adress `ftp://ftpuser@domain`, they could see miniatures of the pictures instead of only their name.

Is it simply possible with ProFTPd or have I to change the way I share my pictures ?

Answer (score 0):

ProFTPd just serves the files which are there. It neither automatically generates thumbnails nor does it care how existing files (i.e. pre-generated thumbnails) are displayed by the client (browser). If you need features like that you should use a web server and not an ftp server.

Comment: Yep, it was what I wondered, but as they were a lot of features options for the web browsers' display, I wanted to ask anyway.